How many elbows can I put in a gutter downspout?
I'm planning on installing gutters this one section will be 38ft no water coming from elsewhere just the one section of roof. 5 inch aluminum gutters.
If I put the downspout at the end it will be under the eve on the side of the house not directly in front of the hoise. So I was thinking I'd angle it in and over to the side of the house. But that would take like 4 bends so I dono if that is too much or if it will restrict water flow or something. Here is the pic of the sid dog the house because I don't think I got what I was saying across. The red is the gutter and the purple is where the downspout will be.


There is nothing in the photo that indicates where you want the downspout to descend.

There is nothing in the photo that indicates which visible wall is the front of the house and which is the side.

Why does the downspout have to be attached to the end of the gutter? Can't you attach it anywhere along the length of the gutter?

My bad, I figure the downspout could come down on the left side of the house.

Also this is the back of the house so the patio is there meaning it needs to be on this corner of the house. It can't go on the other corner because that's the middle of the yard and there is nowhere for the water to drain to. On this corner it's near the edge of the house and it can drain off to the street easily with a conduit

It'd help if you sketched out the downspout and its potential bends.
